# Is there a translation to Lagrange's Réflexions sur la résolution algébrique des équations?

Tags: mathematics, translations

I was interested in reading his work, but I couldn't find a translation in google, is there any? I can understand Spanish and English

Comment: Welcome. Please add all relevant links/full reference data (if any) related to the original work.

Comment: What data/links could be relevant?

Comment: Date, full author's name, journal/book and so on and link to the document if available. It is clear to what you are referring to but it is a good practice to provide full context.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. MAA sponsored a translation by Greg St. George, but only a [couple of pages](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/pubs/mm_supplements/Lagrange_Eq_30.pdf) came out. Barnett has a [guided introduction](https://digitalcommons.ursinus.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1002&context=triumphs_abstract) with some excerpts translated and commented on.

Comment: @Conifold is this really a question about the ***history*** of mathematics or science? Please pardon me if it's on-topic (I may not be familiar enough with what's on-topic).

Comment: @user1271772 Reference requests for original sources of historical works in science and mathematics, and their translations, are traditionally considered on-topic. Sources are the ultimate basis of historical research.

Comment: @Conifold Thank ya for explaining it to me! That helps.